# Cite web page with no author, displaying title without quotes (revtex4.1)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex

I am writing a document using revtex4.1, and I would like to cite some web pages with no particular author in the bibliography.

What I have in mind is pretty simple: I would like the elements to be shown in the bibliography as

```
<Title>, <url>, [Accessed: <access_date>]      (1)
```

The bibliography entry `@online` does not seem to work if the field `author` is omitted. Another option is to use `@misc`, and it is what I have done:

```
\documentclass[aps,jmp,amsmath,amssymb,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@misc{lammps,
    title = {{LAMMPS website}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://lammps.sandia.gov}},
    note = {[Accessed: 10-October-2017]}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\onecolumngrid

See LAMMPS \cite{lammps}.

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

 \end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

This is almost OK. There are, however, two things I would like to change:

1. I would like the title to appear without the quotes.
2. Apparently, there are problems related to the `author` field being empty: all the entries with no author are considered from the *same* author, and if multiple `@misc` entry with no authors are added [this causes problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/strange-appearing-when-using-entry-misc-in-bibliography-revtex4-1).

Is there a way to obtain the result I am looking for (1)? No quotes, no conflict because entries with no author are considered from the same author.

Or is the only option to create my own BibTeX entry style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. By default, revtex4.1 puts footnotes in the bibliography (see the [user guide](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf)). Therefore, I can easily obtain what I am looking for by using a footnote:

```
\documentclass[aps,jmp,amsmath,amssymb,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@misc{lammps,
    title = {{LAMMPS website}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://lammps.sandia.gov}},
    note = {[Accessed: 10-October-2017]}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\onecolumngrid

See LAMMPS \footnote{LAMMPS website, \url{http://lammps.sandia.gov}, [Accessed: 10-October-2017]}.

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

However, two things must be noticed:

1. `\usepackage{hyperref}` must be used instead of `\usepackage{url}`
2. It is necessary to include a bibliography of some kind, even we do not cite anything from it.